# Why does tensorflow's tf.random.uniform run slow on first run?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was running the following code which just makes a call to tf.random.uniform:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time 

g = tf.random.uniform((4,30,30))
sess = tf.Session()

start = time.time()
sess.run(g)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

start = time.time()
sess.run(g)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

My question is: why does the first call to tf.random.uniform run significantly slower than the second?

Comment: I'm not experienced in TF, but isn't it the session setup time, rather than the tf.random.uniform itself? What happens if you assign something else to `g`?

Comment: yes, that seems to be it. thank you.